# Get call history from Get-ScheduledTask

Tags: powershell

Using the Get-Scheduledtask cmdlet, how do I get answers to the following questions:

- When did this scheduled task last run?
- When it last ran, did it succeed or fail?
- What is the schedule for this scheduled task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all of this with the `Get-ScheduledTask` and `Get-ScheduledTaskInfo` cmdlets

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask <TaskName>
$task | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo # Contains LastRunTime,LastTaskResult
# The schedule info is in the triggers
foreach ($Trigger in $task.Triggers) {
    Switch ($Trigger.CimClass.CimClassName) {
        'MSFT_TaskTimeTrigger' { $TriggerWhen = 'Once' }
        'MSFT_TaskBootTrigger' { $TriggerWhen = 'AtStartup' }
        'MSFT_TaskLogonTrigger' { $TriggerWhen = 'AtLogon' }
        'MSFT_TaskWeeklyTrigger' { $TriggerWhen = 'Weekly' }
        'MSFT_TaskDailyTrigger' { $TriggerWhen = 'Daily' }
    }
    # Other properties of the trigger may be useful such as
    $Trigger.WeeksInterval
    $Trigger.DaysOfWeek # Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, Tuesday = 4, Wednesday = 8, Thursday = 16, Friday = 32, Saturday = 64
}
```